# Make list of files on a server inaccessible, but not the files themselves?

Tags: http, directory

I have a directory of files on a web server.  I want the *files* to be accessible, but not the listing of all files in the directory.

- Going to `http://example.com/folder/generic.html` should be fine, you get to see `generic.html`.
- Going to `http://example.com/folder/` should be rejected, you shouldn't get to see a list of the files in the directory.

What flags do I need to set to make this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `.htaccess` file that is in the directory, put the following line:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This disables directory browsing, but the files themselves are still accessible.